# Add version to folder name on publish Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

How do I add the assembly version to "publishUrl" in a Publish Profile?

I know i can add the date to the folder name with this.

```
$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy.MM.dd))
```

But I want to add the assembly version instead.

I have tried working with `$([Class]::Property)` but cant realy get the hang of it.

So if anyone have an example on how to add the assembly version it would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'd like the assembly version in the foldername, so a bit like your question.